# Python3 boolean if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

```
while True:

   x = False

   if x == False:
     if (float) <= (price):
        if not safe_mode:
            (Some function)
     x = True
     print(something)

   elif x == True:
     if (float) >= (price):
        if not safe_mode:
            (Some Function)
     x = False
     print(something)
```

that is my code, and i want that to loop, but what i get is 'x' doesn't want to change value to 'True'... and 'x = True' get grayed out. I don't know why it doesn't want to work, i need all your help pls. i kinda stress finding the problem :(

Comment: side note - you can/should use simply `var` instead of `var == True` in flow control statements.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you set `x` back to `False` at the beginning of each iteration of the `while` loop, so its value is changed within each conditional block, but then changed back to `False` right after when the loop starts over.

Just set `x = False` outside of the `while` loop and that'll solve it. Example:

```
x = False

while True:
    # do stuff
```